# How to share viewPager holder fragment viewModel?

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-hilt

I use viewPager in a fragment, inside viewPager there are 4 fragment. In these fragments I want to use the parent fragment viewModel, but I don't know how to access to parent fragment.

I don't want to use activityViewModels for init viewModel, beacause of lifecycle.

I also use Hilt to inject staff.

So I thouht that, I could pass parent fragment to ViewPagerAdapter, but I can't figure out how to access to this inside fragments?

[Update]
So I modified the pager adapter, and passed the parent fragment, after that, if I call this.parentFragment inside chield fragments, I get the same instance of parent fragment, but I still get a new instance of sharedViewModel

```
**ViewPagerAdapter**

class ReservationMainViewPagerAdapter(
    fragmentManager: FragmentManager,
    lifecycle: Lifecycle,
    private val parentFragment: Fragment
) :
    FragmentStateAdapter(fragmentManager, lifecycle) {
    private var pageCount = 4

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return pageCount
    }

    override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
        return when (position) {
            0 -> DataSheetFragment()
            1 -> ReservationFragment()
            2 -> DocumentUploadFragment()
            3 -> NoteFragment()
            else -> throw Exception("invalid view")
        }
    }

    fun disableLastTwoPage() {
        pageCount = 2
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    fun enableAllPage() {
        pageCount = 4
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
}
**Updated viewPager**
class ReservationMainViewPagerAdapter(
    parentFragment: Fragment
) : FragmentStateAdapter(parentFragment) {


**ViewPager init**
adapter = ReservationMainViewPagerAdapter(childFragmentManager, lifecycle,this)

**Parent fragment viewmodel init**

@AndroidEntryPoint
class DataSheetFragment : BaseBindingFragment<FragmentDataSheetBinding,DataSheetViewModel>() {

    private val viewModel: DataSheetViewModel by viewModels()

    private val reservationMainViewModel: ReservationMainViewModel by viewModels(
        ownerProducer = {this.parentFragment as Fragment}
    )
```

Comment: Looks fine to me, except that passing the parent fragment to the adapter is redundant.  What problem are you facing?

Comment: The problem is that, I get a new ReservationMainViewModel instance every time, instead of one.

Comment: Even with `ownerProducer = {this.parentFragment as Fragment}` (as seen in the code you posted)?

Comment: Yes, for example in the Parent fragment which holds the viewPager, the id of viewmodel is 23015 and inside the another fragment the id is 23021 so not the same instance

Answer (score 3):

So finally, I find the mistake. I injected parent view model into parent fragment like this:

```
    private val reservationMainViewModel: ReservationMainViewModel by viewModels(
        ownerProducer = {this.parentFragment as Fragment}
    )
```

So therefore doesn't matched the viewModel.